# What do the attributes 'final' and 'block' mean in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

In XSD, < complextType > can have the attributes 'block' and 'final', which can take a value of #all or a list of extensions or restrictions. What do these attributes mean? How do we use them?

I could not get a clear answer from [the W3C recommendation for XSD 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-1-20120405/). Could someone give me some examples?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As is so often the case with XML Schema, the non-normative "primer" provides a much clearer explanation than the normative specs. In this case the section ["controlling the creation and use of derived types"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#restrictingTypeDerivs) has a worked example of both `final` and `block` in terms of different types of address.

Essentially, `final` means that the type cannot have any subtypes at all (with the appropriate derivation style), whereas `block` says that the type *can* have subtypes but when an element is declared to be of a blocked type then that element must be of the declared type specifically, and not of a subtype.

Comment: Getting that explanation into three lines is brilliant. The actual rules are horrendous, and I wouldn't advise anyone to use the feature for that reason, but this is a pretty good short summary.

Answer (score 0):

A sample test done with sample XSD and XML snippet available in spec using the eclipse XSD/XML validation feature:

1. Restricting derivation of types using **final**

<<**ipo.xsd**>>

```
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/IPO" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:ipo="http://www.example.com/IPO">
<complexType name="Address" block="extension">
    <sequence>
        <element name="name" type="string" />
        <element name="street" type="string" />
        <element name="city" type="string" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="USAddress">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="ipo:Address">
            <sequence>
                <element name="state" type="ipo:USState" />
                <element name="zip" type="positiveInteger" />
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
<complexType name="UKAddress">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="ipo:Address">
            <sequence>
                <element name="postcode" type="ipo:UKPostcode" />
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="exportCode" type="positiveInteger" fixed="1" />
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
<!-- other Address derivations for more countries -->
<simpleType name="USState">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="AK" />
        <enumeration value="AL" />
        <enumeration value="AR" />
        <!-- and so on ... -->
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
<!-- simple type definition for UKPostcode -->
<simpleType name="UKPostcode">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="PO16" />
        <enumeration value="G41" />
        <enumeration value="WC1A" />
        <!-- and so on ... -->
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
....
....
```

[Screenshot of **ipo.xsd** validation errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKc0J.png)

2. Restricting which derivation can be used in instance documents using **block**

<<**ipo.xsd**>>

```
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/IPO" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:ipo="http://www.example.com/IPO">   
      <complexType name="Address" block="extension">
        <sequence>
          <element name="name" type="string"/>
          <element name="street" type="string"/>
          <element name="city" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <complexType name="USAddress">
        <complexContent>
          <extension base="ipo:Address">
            <sequence>
              <element name="state" type="ipo:USState"/>
              <element name="zip" type="positiveInteger"/>
            </sequence>
          </extension>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
      <complexType name="UKAddress">
        <complexContent>
          <extension base="ipo:Address">
            <sequence>
              <element name="postcode" type="ipo:UKPostcode"/>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="exportCode" type="positiveInteger" fixed="1"/>
          </extension>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
      .....
      .....
    </schema>
```

<<**ipo.xml**>>

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ipo:purchaseOrder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ipo="http://www.example.com/IPO"
                   orderDate="1999-12-01"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/IPO ipo.xsd">

  <shipTo  xsi:type="ipo:UKAddress" exportCode="1">
    <name>Helen Zoe</name>
    <street>47 Eden Street</street>
    <city>Cambridge</city>
    <postcode>WC1A</postcode>
  </shipTo>
  <billTo xsi:type="ipo:USAddress">
    <name>Robert Smith</name>
    <street>8 Oak Avenue</street>
    <city>Old Town</city>
    <state>AL</state>
    <zip>95819</zip>
  </billTo>
  <items>
    <item partNum="833-AA">
      <productName>Lapis necklace</productName>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <USPrice>99.95</USPrice>
      <ipo:comment>Want this for the holidays!</ipo:comment>
      <shipDate>1999-12-05</shipDate>
    </item>
  </items>
</ipo:purchaseOrder>
```

[Screenshot of **ipo.xml** validation errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd5WJ.png)
Note that ipo.xsd validation shows no error for the 2nd case (using block="extension").